# The variable index isn't increasnig when I press the continue button because the function isn't being called even though the screenshots say it is

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

[image: Screenshots]

[image: More screenshots]

```
public void Continue10()
{
    dialogue = true;
    index += 1;
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            text.text = "Prime and Primal welcome to Earth!";
            image.sprite = mirage;
            break;
        case 1:
            conversation.SetActive(false);
            anim.SetTrigger("throw");
            Instantiate(transwarpKey, point.position, Quaternion.identity);
            break;
    }
}
```

In this code whenever I click the continue button(See in screenshots for continue button) the index should increase by 1 but it doesn't.

Comment: Does the button react to interaction at all (e.g. hover)? If not something is overlapping the button and blocking the raycasts and your button isn't even hit by the cursor ...

Answer (score 0):

Put Debug.Log to print index value before and after index+=1. May be you are resetting it elsewhere.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't print anything meaning that the function isn't being called